# Wanting to take the highest and lowest 25% of a table

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, resampling

Hello as far as I could find there is no real solution for my task yet. (If there is please just let me know and I will take advice from there)

But without writing more unnecessary now:
I would like to get the highest and lowest 25% (or other percentages possible) values from a table (example see below). This involves several columns (4 to be exact) that have the highest and lowest values.

About my data:
Have a panel regression (with time series), which I analyze by `influence.measures`. This function gives the extreme values (similar to `gvlma`).

Then, since the number is quite high (+300 for a dataset of almost 3600 variables (or is this not much?)) I want to remove only the highest 25% and lowest 25% of the variables, from the table.
My function for this is as follows:

```
lm.01 <-lm(log(x) ~ log(intr) + log(y) + log(z) + factor(dummy)
           , data=r1.2) 

unnecessary_data1 <- influence.measures(lm.01)
table_u_d1 <- summary(unnecessary_data1)

drops1.2 <- c()
#in c() should the variables be included that should get excluded

r1.2 = r1.1
#r is my data set

r1.2 <- r1.2[-drops1.2,]
```

Output of `table_u_d1` looks something like this (only the columns that should be necessary (there are more but those are not relevant):

|  | example row | dffit | cov.r | cook.d | hat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | -0.003754 | -0.11643 | 0.972833 | 0.000972 | 0.001587 |
| 10 | -0.056679 | -0.09812 | 0.985349 | 0.000693 | 0.000687 |
| 100 | 0.005639 | -0.23096 | 0.995242 | 0.003839 | 0.010623 |
| 301 | 0.006557 | -0.24344 | 0.993736 | 0.004269 | 0.010729 |
| 490 | -0.003771 | -0.26348 | 1.015349 | 0.004991 | 0.010783 |
| 510 | -0.020162 | -0.23365 | 1.014367 | 0.003869 | 0.010551 |
| 530 | -0.007013 | 0.07778 | 1.005749 | 0.004319 | 0.012449 |
| 720 | -0.015032 | -0.06255 | 1.010301 | 0.001425 | 0.010034 |
| 1120 | -0.003564 | -0.04462 | 1.019249 | 0.000053 | 0.010329 |
| 1320 | 0.000003 | -0.00134 | 1.025679 | 0.004878 | 0.010186 |

I need the value of the first column as the result, because this indicates the position in the regression and only so I can use drops. And I need the values that have the highest and lowest 25% values in `dffit`, `cov.r`, `cook.d` and `hat`.

Maybe it could be useful for the exemplary data set that not the top and bottom 25% are used, but less. Need but please also a solution with 25% :).

If any further information are needed just let me know :)

Need help to loop and to get the final information
I have found now this way to get the information:

```
dffit.75.1<-data.frame(table_u_d1) %>% 
  filter(quantile(dffit, 0.75)<dffit)
dffit.25.1<-data.frame(table_u_d1) %>% 
  filter(quantile(dffit, 0.25)>dffit)

cov.r.75.1<-data.frame(table_u_d1) %>% 
  filter(quantile(cov.r, 0.75)<cov.r)
cov.r.25.1<-data.frame(table_u_d1) %>% 
  filter(quantile(cov.r, 0.25)>cov.r)

cook.d.75.1<-data.frame(table_u_d1) %>% 
  filter(quantile(cook.d, 0.75)<cook.d)
cook.d.25.1<-data.frame(table_u_d1) %>% 
  filter(quantile(cook.d, 0.25)>cook.d)

hat.75.1<-data.frame(table_u_d1) %>% 
  filter(quantile(hat, 0.75)<hat)
hat.25.1<-data.frame(table_u_d1) %>% 
  filter(quantile(hat, 0.25)>hat)
```

But afterwards it does not help to get a complete data

```
dffit.1<-rbind(dffit.25.1,dffit.75.1)
cov.r.1<-rbind(cov.r.25.1,cov.r.75.1)
....
```

Because the output would just always double the amount of the data (so duplicates are not recognised)

Comment: Can you add the output of `dput(table_u_d1)`. It'll be easier for us to reproduce this table...

Comment: Okay, but I had to shorten the regression so the output of dput would fit in the console. Therefore only 2 variables are still included in the regression

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this, just filter on the value you can find using the `quantile` function.

```
df <- data.frame(var = sample(1:100, 50))

df %>% filter(var > quantile(var, 0.75)) # gives you the highest 25%
df %>% filter(var < quantile(var, 0.25)) # gives you the lowest 25%

# combine to keep all except smallest 25% and biggest 25%
df %>% filter(var > quantile(var, 0.25) & var < quantile(var, 0.75))
```

Comment: Okay, the first approach would then be the correct approach for me, because I then have to subtract the variables from the entire data set (in the list are not all data, only those with extreme values). However, there is a problem: how do I get the combination of all at the end? Because otherwise I have 300*0.25*2*4=600 variables, which are partly duplicated and are not yet in a listing, so that I can simply insert them at c(). Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: If you want to have a data-frame with low and high quartile of each variable, then you can apply a function over each column, which replace by NA, each value inside Q1-Q3

Comment: @YacineHajji I am not quite sure what you want to tell me? Why would I want to replace my values by NA? Do you mean that than I can filter the data set so that NA´s get deleted and now I got a list of my wanted data? Could you please send an example for that?